# Node version error during Salesforce DX pre-release plugin installation

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, node.js, cli, pre-release

When installing the Salesforce CLI with the Spring '21 pre-release Salesforce DX plugin, I'm getting an incompatible node version error.

This command:

```sh
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Results in this error:

> The engine “node” is incompatible with this module. Expected version “>=14". Got “12.18.3”

Comment: We've started getting similar error on our pipelines since today, but we are using stable version: sfdx-cli/7.85.0 with node 10. After trying to install sfpowerkit plugin, we've got an error message: [ "The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "10.17.0" ] Everything was fine just yesterday. Seems like issue is a bit broader than just in scope of pre-release version.

Answer (score 4):

This error shows up even if you have the right node version installed in your environment. The reason why this happens is that the default Salesforce CLI installation ships with a node server bundled with it.

As of today (2020-01-18), the internal node version shipped with the CLI is `12.18.3` and the issue is that the pre-release Salesforce DX plugin expects node v14 or higher.

**Workarounds:**

- wait for an update of the core CLI which will update the built-in node server (waiting for an ETA on this but it should be pretty soon).
- install a v14 node server yourself and [install the Salesforce CLI as a node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-cli).

Comment: "No software" ;)

Comment: Joke aside, I believe that the "no software" tagline applies to users, not developers.